# Insert Into Database doesn't work for css-like string

Tags: sql

I have the following problem: I want to insert something in the SQL database, but I get a syntax error. This is the code:

`mysql_query("INSERT INTO wp_postmeta (meta_key, post_id, meta_value)
VALUES ('_product_attributes','$postid','a:1:{s:7:"pa_maat";a:6:{s:4:"name";s:7:"pa_maat";s:5:"value";s:0:"";s:8:"position";s:1:"5";s:10:"is_visible";i:0;s:12:"is_variation";i:1;s:11:"is_taxonomy";i:1;}}')");`

I know it has something to do with the meta_value entry, but I dont know how to put it in.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
This is the error message:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING

Comment: escape double quotes inside query

Comment: Could you please give an example?

Comment: rtfm - http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Sorry but I dont understand how this will help me. I only need to put this text: a:1:{s:7:"pa_maat";a:6:{s:4:"name";s:7:"pa_maat";s:5:"value";s:0:"";s:8:"position";s:1:"5";s:10:"is_visible";i:0;s:12:"is_variation";i:1;s:11:"is_taxonomy";i:1;}} as a value for the insert. Thanks for the patience if this is too easy for you.

Comment: @MShahzadKhan: you don't need to escape double quotes in string literals, only single quotes. (double quotes are only used around object names in SQL, single quotes are used to specify a string literal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For successful execution use bind query format in this case rather than direct value assignment.

Comment: Ok i did the following:
`$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO wp_postmeta (meta_key, post_id, meta_value)
VALUES (:meta, :postid, :metav)");
$stmt -> bindParam(':meta', '_product_attributes');
$stmt -> bindParam(':postid', $postid);
$stmt -> bindParam(':metav', 'a:1:{s:7:"pa_maat";a:6:{s:4:"name";s:7:"pa_maat";s:5:"value";s:0:"";s:8:"position";s:1:"5";s:10:"is_visible";i:0;s:12:"is_variation";i:1;s:11:"is_taxonomy";i:1;}}');
$stmt -> execute();`
this gives an error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object

Comment: how are you creating $dbh ?? Please check http://docs.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Comment: This is how: $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=test', $dbuser, $dbpass);

Comment: use $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.$dbhost.';dbname=test', $dbuser, $dbpass);

Comment: Now I get the following error:
Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference on line 56 which is : $stmt -> bindParam(':meta', '_product_attributes');
Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: The error means that the 2nd argument is expected to be a reference to a variable.

Since you are not handing a variable but an string of value _product_attributes, it generates said error.

To circumvent this do: $stmt -> bindParam(':meta', $attr = '_product_attributes');
hopefully this will work :)

Comment: Ok that problem is solved, but the original problem still exist. Now i have: $stmt -> bindParam(':metav', $pa); and $pa = "a:1:{s:7:"pa_maat";a:6:{s:4:"name";s:7:"pa_maat";s:5:"value";s:0:"";s:8:"positi‌​on";s:1:"5";s:10:"is_visible";i:0;s:12:"is_variation";i:1;s:11:"is_taxonomy";i:1;‌​}}"; but this gives the error: unexpected T_STRING

Comment: use $pa = 'a:1:{s:7:"pa_maat";a:6:{s:4:"name";s:7:"pa_maat";s:5:"value";s:0:"";s:8:"positi‌​‌​on";s:1:"5";s:10:"is_visible";i:0;s:12:"is_variation";i:1;s:11:"is_taxonomy";i:‌​1;‌​}}';

Comment: My pleasure.. :)
 In case you want to understand what is happening, as opposed to just fixing your Fatal error, read this: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php